# inherit and initial acting the same

Tags: javascript, css

When pushing the "change" button the style never returns to the declared CSS style (purple on black) - "initial" and "inherit" are acting the same here...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  section {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: purple;
  }
  .demo {
    color: purple;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>

<button id="change">Change</button>

<section>
  <p class="demo">Demo text</p>
  <button class="demo">demo button</button>
  <input class="demo" type="text" placeholer="demo field" />
</section>

<script>
  var flipColors = document.getElementById("change");
  var demoFlip = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  demoFlip.toggleStatus = "onColor";
  flipColors.onclick = function() {
    switch (demoFlip.toggleStatus) {
      case "onColor":
        demoFlip.toggleStatus = "flipColor";
        for (i = 0; i < demoFlip.length; i++) {
          demoFlip[i].style.color = "blue";
          demoFlip[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        break;
      case "flipColor":
        demoFlip.toggleStatus = "off";
        for (i = 0; i < demoFlip.length; i++) {
          demoFlip[i].style.color = "yellow";
          demoFlip[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
        break;
      case "off":
        demoFlip.toggleStatus = "onColor";
        for (i = 0; i < demoFlip.length; i++) {
          demoFlip[i].style.color = "inherit";
          demoFlip[i].style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
        }
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Should I declare colours here? I know that it's simple but I can't figure what am I missing here?

Comment: Your snippet resets the background but not the text color. When I use `initial` both work fine. Tested in Vivaldi (Chrome based).

Comment: i thought there is a keyword like "inherit" or "initial" that can restore the class. i understand there isn't. thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yes there is. I just don't know why it doesn't work for you. Which browser did you try it on?

Comment: firefox, but i try to use simple JS and CSS that should work with all major browsers from the last 2-3 years. i think that the best thing to do is to use special class (demo1 for example), and apply it on the 3rd case (as returning to default). in my openion it sily to write the same thing on two diffrent classes but i can't find a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

"Inherit" means it will take the defined value of the parent. In this case, the parent is  which is yellow on purple. So when the switch is "off" it turns to inherit, so it turns to section values.

If you want to use "inherit" and you want to keep the section designed as it is, you may wrap the things in another container.

Otherwise, you could define the colors in the case "off".

The way I would do it though is to make a CSS class for each version and add/remove it.

Functional code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  section {
    color: purple;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .demo {
    color: purple;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>

<button id="change">Change</button>

<section>
  <p class="demo">Demo text</p>
  <button class="demo">demo button</button>
  <input class="demo" type="text" placeholer="demo field" />
</section>

<script>
  var flipColors = document.getElementById("change");
  var demoFlip = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  demoFlip.toggleStatus = "onColor";
  flipColors.onclick = function() {
    switch (demoFlip.toggleStatus) {
      case "onColor":
        demoFlip.toggleStatus = "flipColor";
        for (i = 0; i < demoFlip.length; i++) {
          demoFlip[i].style.color = "blue";
          demoFlip[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        break;
      case "flipColor":
        demoFlip.toggleStatus = "off";
        for (i = 0; i < demoFlip.length; i++) {
          demoFlip[i].style.color = "yellow";
          demoFlip[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
        break;
      case "off":
        demoFlip.toggleStatus = "onColor";
        for (i = 0; i < demoFlip.length; i++) {
          demoFlip[i].style.color = "inherit";
          demoFlip[i].style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
        }
        break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: hi, didn't see that you change something on the code. i don't want to wrap it more, maybe i just use the class. i thought there is a keyword like "inherit" or "initial" that can restore the class. i understand there isn't. thank you.

Comment: @A.Meshu, I just added different styles to <section>